# How to pass bash variables to awk script

Tags: awk, gawk

```
# My vars 
  index=test
  type=book
```

I'm trying to pass these variables to awk

```
  awk -v index="$index" -v type="$type" 'BEGIN{print "{\"create\": {\"_index\":\"index\", \"_type\":\"type\"}}"}; {print}; END {printf "\n"}'
```

Desired output

```
{"create": {"_index":"test", "_type":"book"}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't embed the variables in the string:

```
awk -v idx="$index" -v type="$type" 'BEGIN{print "{\"create\": {\"_index\":\"" idx "\", \"_type\":\"" type "\"}}"} {print} END {print ""}'
```

You can't use `index` as an awk variable name, btw, as that's the name of an awk function.

Comment: Thanks Ed, you are always helpful